How to help document Ubuntu?
I am a technical writer with plenty of open source experience and I would like to help document Ubuntu. Where is the best place to start?

Which part of Ubuntu do you want to document?

You can write tutorials about Ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/tutorials. You can find a link therein about how to start the process.

Shoutout to technical writers! More technical writing should be done by technical writers. At my employer, most technical writing is done by engineers, and I personally consider it a mistake. It's basically a waste of time and money, since engineers need more time to write lower quality documentation than a technical writer would need. Open Source documentation often sucks because often, the developer is also the primary user, so it's someone who is not trained in writing, writing documentation for himself about a thing he already knows how it works.

I have merely heard of it, but the interaction of systemd with the rest of the system seems to be of interest to some people.

There is the Open Documentation Academy initiative from Canonical, which pursues:

The Open Documentation Academy combines Canonical’s documentation team with documentation newcomers, experts, and those in-between, to help us all improve documentation practice and become better writers.

One can find issues in the GitHub repo, a forum and even Youtube videos with office hours.
